# How to use Vue watch to observe a form item value?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, watch, element-ui

```
<el-form-item label="range"
              v-if="isShowDatepicker">
    <el-date-picker type="datetimerange" 
                                    style="width: 100%"
                                    v-model="timeRange"
                                    range-separator="to"
                                    start-placeholder="start"
                                    end-placeholder="end"></el-date-picker>
</el-form-item>
```

I have a form that has an item to input `date` and `time` (just like the code above), and I want to obtain the value after it has changed. I want to use Vue `watch` to accomplish this task. However, I don't know how to name the variable in `watch`. I've tried this:

```
"SearchForm.timeRange": function (val) {
     console.log(val)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) data changes using the [`watch` object](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch), add a function to that object with a name matching the data property to watch. For instance, to watch a data property named `"question"`, add this function:

```
watch: {
  question(newValue, oldValue) {
    //...
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could add an object named after the target data property, with a `handler` function and additional watcher options: `deep` and `immediate`.

```
watch: {
  question: {
    deep: true,      // detecting nested changes in objects
    immediate: true, // triggering the handler immediately with the current value
    handler(newValue, oldValue) {
      //...
    }
  }
}
```

---

In your case with `"timeRange"`, the syntax would be:

```
watch: {
  timeRange(newValue) {
    //...
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/rRxwEY?editors=1010)

Comment: I've tried like this: `timeRange: function(val) {
      console.log(val)
     }`,
It didn't work either.@tony19

Comment: Hmm. Can you provide more context to reproduce the problem? How is the `timeRange` property declared?

Comment: `data() {
        return {
            SearchForm: {
             searchWord: '',
             timeRange: ''
            },
            isShowDatepicker: false,
            searchType: 'all',
            timeRange: ''
        };`
the whole form is declared like the above code.and the function in watch like this
`timeRange: function(val) {
      console.log(val)
     }`

Comment: See updated answer for a demo. If your use case is different, it would be helpful to see a codepen that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Okay I thought my question has been solved, thank you so much~By the way, codepen is really a useful tool for programmers,

Comment: @wangzewei No problem :) I'm glad the Codepen helped you. There's also [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) (which is great for SFC demos). I highly recommend using them for reproductions in your next questions. Happy coding!

Comment: Okay I'll try it later, and I love SO so much~ in which I could learn so much coding thing.And happy coding too, I suppose to be a happy programmer~